# Newly created migrations from package after vendor publish are not executed with artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I'm new to creating package in laravel. I've made a survey package and inside package I've made following directory structure.

[image: Screenshot]

Now, I've loaded files from service provider as follows,

**SurveyServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace Survey;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class SurveyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    
    $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes/web.php');
    $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/./../publishables/database/migrations');
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/./../resources/views/','survey');
}

public function register()
{
    $this->registerPublishables();
}

private function registerPublishables()
{
    $basePath = dirname(__DIR__);

    $arrPublishable = [
        'migrations' => [
            "$basePath/publishables/database/migrations" => database_path('migrations'),
            "$basePath/publishables/config/survey.php" => config_path('survey.php'),
      ]
    ];

    foreach ($arrPublishable as $group => $paths) {
        $this->publishes($paths,$group);
    }
}
}
```

My migration file is created after `vendor:publish` command

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAuditsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('audits', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->boolean('is_published');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('audits');
}
}
```

But, when I execute `php artisan migrate` audit migration file not executed any reason over there.

One more thing, I've already executed `composer dumpautoload` command

Please ask if you want any further detail.

Comment: what happens when `php artisan migrate` execute? any errors.

Comment: No errors, only users and password resets table are migrated but not audits table

Comment: check in the `migrations` table, maybe there is an entry as audit table. if there is, remove it an try again

Comment: @TharakaDilshan There is no audit table in migrations table, so i've deleted whole database and created new still same problem

Comment: check config/app.php file are exist in your project?